# What is the better way of handling Sqlite3 CORRUPT error (11) in C program?

Tags: c, sqlite

I have seen many articles regarding the **Sqlite3 database disk image is malformed** issue in stack overflow. But i would like to know how to handle this **SQLITE_CORRUPT (error code: 11)** error in C program, when it happens during the production server.

### Sample Program

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int insert_records_to_database(sqlite3 *db)
{
   char *err_msg = 0;
   char *sql_in = "INSERT INTO Vehicles VALUES(1, 'maruthi', 5264);"
                "INSERT INTO Vehicles VALUES(2, 'tesla', 5712);"
                "INSERT INTO Vehicles VALUES(3, 'Skoda', 900);"
                "INSERT INTO Vehicles VALUES(4, 'suzuki', 2900);"
                "INSERT INTO Vehicles VALUES(5, 'ferrari', 35000);"
                "INSERT INTO Vehicles VALUES(6, 'Citroen', 2100);"
                "INSERT INTO Vehicles VALUES(7, 'honda', 4140);"
                "INSERT INTO Vehicles VALUES(8, 'fiat', 2160);";

    int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql_in, 0, 0, &err_msg);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK ) {
        if(rc == SQLITE_CORRUPT)
        {
           printf(" SQLITE Database is corrupted :: How to handle");
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", err_msg);
        sqlite3_free(err_msg);
        sqlite3_close(db);

        return 1;
    }
  return 0;
}
int main(void) {

    sqlite3 *db;
    char *err_msg = 0;

    int rc = sqlite3_open("/root/sqlite3/test.db", &db);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return 1;
    }

    char *sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Vehicles;"
                "CREATE TABLE Vehicles(Id INT, Name TEXT, Price INT);" ;

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, 0, 0, &err_msg);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", err_msg);
        sqlite3_free(err_msg);
        sqlite3_close(db);

        return 1;
    }


    insert_records_to_database(db);


    sqlite3_close(db);

    return 0;
}
```

-> In the above program, i am exiting from the program when such kind of error occurs. But still the corrupt **test.db** exists and no action taken on test.db. For suppose, if i want to use the same DB to insert the records, shall end up with the same errors as disk image is malformed, it can't insert the records.

-> How to handle this case when the program is continuously trying to insert data in to corrupted database? Is there any efficient way of handling this kind of issue.

```
if (rc == SQLITE_CORRUPT)
{
     printf(" SQLITE Database is corrupted :: How to handle");
}
```

I have work around:

> Remove the test.db
>   (or) Re run the program once gain to create test.db freshly.

Scenario: If the program runs in infinite loop, the database(**test.db**) is created during start of the program. After that when program receives data from kernel every 15 min, and inserts the same data in to sqlite3 during that time if corruption is seen then insertion shall fail. How to handle this case efficiently?

Comment: You can try and `dump` the test.db and save the result to a new database file, and see if you have saved anything useful.   The sqlite `.dump` command will generate the sql that you need to create the new database.

Comment: .dump will show the commands and error as disk malformed. But i need to handle the case gracefully when this occurs during run time.

Comment: I'd focus more on figuring out what causes the corruption and fix that. You shouldn't be having this problem unless your code is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your scenario: If the program runs in infinite loop, the database(test.db) is created during start of the program. After that when program receives data from kernel every 15 min, and inserts the same data in to sqlite3 during that time if corruption is seen then insertion shall fail. How to handle this case efficiently?

Design your code as below:

Solution 1:

```
if (rc != SQLITE_OK ) {
        if(rc == SQLITE_CORRUPT)
        {
           printf(" SQLITE Database is corrupted :: How to handle");
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", err_msg);
        sqlite3_free(err_msg);
        sqlite3_close(db);

        # Remove the database file
        remove("test.db");
        # Then exit
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Ideally your application should create new test.db if the file doesn't exit.

Solution 2:

Maintain a global variable for continuous running of application as

```
    global_variable =0
     while(!global_variable) { 
       }
```

When this error occurs, raise SIGINT to gracefully shutdown your application. You need to have signal handler to capture the SIGINT and this stop your process.

```
   if (rc != SQLITE_OK ) {
        if(rc == SQLITE_CORRUPT)
        {
           printf(" SQLITE Database is corrupted :: How to handle");
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", err_msg);
        sqlite3_free(err_msg);
        sqlite3_close(db);

        # Remove the database file
        remove("test.db");
        # Raise SIGINT
        raise(SIGINT);
    }


# Register SIGINT
 signal(SIGINT, signal_catchfunc);

void signal_catchfunc(int signal) {
   global_variable=1
   printf("!! signal caught !!\n");
}
```